# Embedding SWFs via SSL issue. (Sound, but no video on certain players)

Tags: ssl, https, flash, embed

I have a problem with embedding SWFs via SSL.

I know that the common misconception with embedding SWFs on secure pages is that people always try to embed it using a non-secure link. This isn't the case, as I am trying to host the SWF and swfobject.js locally using relative paths to account for the use of SSL.

It appears that the first of these players (under ssl) will play the audio playback, but won't display the video, while the second one will render the entire SWF fine.

Here are 2 examples that are EXTREMELY similiar. Unfortunately I can only post 2 hyperlinks, so you'll have to swap the http: protocol with https: to see how each player renders under SSL.

These 2 players are using 2 different SWF's, so I'm lead to believe it's a Flash/ActionScript issue, but I have failed to isolate it.

#### Example 1

[Non-secure working embed](http://www.gmwebcast.com/embed.php)

#### Example 2

[Non-secure working embed](http://www.gmwebcast.com/embed2.php)

Answer (score 0):

First, Mixed http & https are different domains that run afoul of the Adobe Flash Player's same-domain security restriction. Using a cross-domain file on the root of your server will allow access.

Second, IE has some known problems with SWF and SSL.

Third, be sure to enable https and check to ensure you have a valid root certificate.

Without more information, this is the best I can do.

The best way is to test your work using the Debug Version of Flash Player. This works best in Firefox. Chances are there is something (dependency or resource) that the player is trying to get without SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have provided 2 examples of 2 (almost) identical players. Flash does request some resources outside of SSL, but IE and other browsers are very naive when it comes to plugins using their own XHRs to request these resources.